# Save entity containing gson atribute to ElasticSearch in Spring

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, gson, spring-data-elasticsearch

My Spring application uses Spring-data-elasticsearch (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch).

I would like to save following document to the elasticsearch database:

```
    @Document(indexName = "documents", type = "customEntity", replicas = 0, shards = 5)
    public class CustomEntity implements Serializable{

        @Id
        private String Id;  
        @Field(type = FieldType.String)
        private String Field1;
        @Field(type = FieldType.Integer)
        private int Field2;
        @Field(type = FieldType.Object)  //not sure which annotation I should use
        private JsonObject exportJSON;   //gson object

        ...getters and setters...
    }
```

using this way:

```
public class CustomEntityDao {

    @Resource
    ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;        

    public void insertCustomEntity(CustomEntity entity){        

        IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQuery();
        indexQuery.setId(entity.getCustomEntityId());
        indexQuery.setObject(entity);

        elasticsearchTemplate.index(indexQuery);  //exception thrown

    }   

}
```

but I'm getting this error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject
>   (through reference chain: data.nosql.entities.CustomEntity
>   ["exportJSON"]->com.google.gson.JsonObject["asString"])

I understand the problem but I don't have clue how to solve it. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that jackson tries to covert your gson object to a string to be indexable by ES and it doesn't know how to do that. If you post your full stack trace it'll be more helpful, but if i have to take a guess you need to use a @JsonSerializer annotation on your "exportJSON" object.